# What are French equivalents to the English “um”, “so”, “uh”, etc.?

Tags: oral, onomatopées

I'm talking about [Speech disfluency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_disfluency) or hesitations in speech while your brain is still thinking about what to say.  “Um, er, uh, so, yeah, you know, like, etc.”

In French, how are these expressed?  What are some common [filler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filler_%28linguistics%29) phrases attached to the beginning of sentences that are simply said while the person is still piecing together a coherent thought?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

- *Euh*
- *Hmmm*, *hum*
- *Eh bien* (sometimes spelled *et bien*) and relatives: *eh ben*, *ben*, *bah*, and especially in the south *eh beh* (pronounced *é bé*),
- *Tu vois* (may be phonetically contracted in *tvois*)
- *Tu sais* (may be phonetically contracted in *tsé*)
- *Enfin*
- *Quoi* as a postfix
- Any combination of the above : for instance, a whole sentence with only these (that may actually be uttered) : *euh, bah tu sais, ben enfin tu vois quoi*

Answer (score 9):

“*mmm*”, “*tu vois*” and “*en fait*” are the most used currently.

Answer (score 8):

*Euh* and *ben* (I've also seen it spelled *bun*; etymologically related to *bien*).

Comment: It's always "ben", "bun" doesn't exist. But I agree these are the most common.

Comment: I've seen it spelled _bun_. There is likely no standard for such an informal word. But I'll edit my post to place "ben" in the seat of honor here.

Comment: "bun"? never saw it.. where was it?

Comment: I am with @Louhike on that: pretty sure "bun" doesn't exist. It sounds awfully suspiciously like an English spelling of the sound (doubt a French speaker would pronounce it the way of "ben").

Answer (score 4):

I use *hum*. Sometimes *hum hum*.

Comment: Ca se prononce comment?

Comment: @Vincent : pronounced "eum"

Answer (score 4):

On top of the answers already listed on this page, we also say *Alors !* in certain circumstances:

> — Ca s'est bien passé ton examen ?
>   — Alors ! Oui, au début, mais lorsqu'ils ont commencé à me poser des questions [...]

Or also:

> — Que pensez-vous de ce projet ?
>   — Alors ! L'idée est séduisante, c'est certain. Je me demande juste si nous avons les fonds nécessaires.

I'd say this is an equivalent of *Well!*.

Answer (score 3):

In Québécois French it's pretty common for people to say "umm" just like in English.